# active mq delay recovery

Tags: activemq-classic, apache-storm

I'm trying to use an ActiveMQ queue as a Apache Storm Spout.

I use the "INDIVIDUAL_ACK" strategy.

In my idea, I'm planning to trigger a session.recover() periodically, to resend messages that would not be acknowledged (error in the Bolt processing chain).

But if I do that, all the messages corresponding to Storm tuple, currently processed, would be resent. I would try to limit this phenomenon.

Ideally, I would like to parameter a delay, all the message sent younger that this delay should not be resent (this delay should also be in phase with the timeout of Storm tuple processing)

I've read about AMQ policies (http://activemq.apache.org/redelivery-policy.html) but I'm not sure that the redeliveryDelay param applies to my problem.

Any hint?

Franck

Answer (score 0):

With INDIVIDUAL_ACKNOWLEDGE you don't use a session.recover(), you do a message.acknowledge(). Additionally, its best practice to only use JMS-style transactions for automatically recoverable errors (ie. host is down). For a contextual issue (ie.. bad data) that will never work, you should move the message to another queue.. i.e. some .DLQ or .ERR queue.